# c# pass method into parameter for logging

Tags: c#, .net

I am implementing simple logging, and I would like to do something like below

```
public int SomeMethod(int x)
{
  Log(SomeMethod,"here is a log entry);
}
```

In the Log method, I would like to parse out the class name from the method and print to the log file the method name and class name.

Is it possible to do something that would look as simple as above or something similar?

Comment: You could use a delegate function to pass an actual function, defined either locally in the SomeMethod scope or more broadly in the class or similar that contains SomeMethod.

Answer (score -1):

Try this with Reflection

```
var currentMethodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
var currentCalssName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
```

Or you can implement your Log method like these

```
public static void Log<TCallerClass>(string text, [CallerMemberName]string method = "")
{
var callerMethodName = method;
var callerCalssName = typeof(TCallerClass).FullName;
}
```

Usage : `Log<YourClass>("here is a log entry");`

```
public static void Log(string text)
{
var stackFrame = new StackFrame(1, true);
var callerMethodName = stackFrame.GetMethod().Name;
var callerCalssName = stackFrame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
}
```

Usage : `Log("here is a log entry");`

Answer (score -1):

you could use [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) if you are using C# 6 or later

```
public int SomeMethod(int x)
{
  Log(nameof(SomeMethod), "here is a log entry");
}
```